# Can we calculate the spectral radius of the universal cover for specific graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, covering, ramanujan, spectral-radius

### Background

For a finite graph $G$, let $\tilde{G}$ denote the [universal cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_graph#Universal_cover) of $G$. For a vertex $v$, let $p_{2n}(v)$ denote the number of paths of length $2n$ that start and end at $v$. The spectral radius of $\tilde{G}$, denoted $\rho(\tilde{G})$, is equal to
$$
\rho(\tilde{G})=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} p_{2n}(v)^{\frac{1}{2n}}
$$
for any vertex $v\in\tilde{G}$.

**Known Examples:**

For some graphs, the combinatorics of counting pathes simplifies greatly. For $d$-regular graphs, the cover is the $d$-regular tree, and the spectral radius of the universal cover, the $d$-regular tree, equals $2\sqrt{d-1}$.

For [biregular graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biregular_graph), with degrees $d_1,d_2$, calculating the number of paths can be similarly done, and the universal cover has radius $\sqrt{d_1-1}+\sqrt{d_2-1}$.

### Question

Can we explicitly calculate the radius of the universal cover for other irregular graphs? I couldn't find any explicit examples in the literature other than the two mentioned above.

I would specifically like to know how to calculate it for the following two cases:

1. Let $G_1$ denote $K_4$ minus an edge. What is $\rho(\tilde{G}_1)$? Numerically, it is around $~2.508\dots $
2. Let $G_2$ denote $K_5$ minus an edge. What is $\rho(\tilde{G}_2)$? Numerically, it is around $~3.262\dots $

The problem I run into when trying to calculate the number of paths in $\tilde{G}_1$ is that backtracking changes the distribution of vertices, potentially in a complicated way with multiple backtracks, but I might be missing something.

Comment: I'm not sure this helps, but have you considered the question as a question in electrical currents? See "Random walks and electric networks" from Doyle & Snell or the book by Lyons & Peres "Probability on trees and networks".

Comment: Maybe a comparison to the Cayley graph of the fundamental group could help. You fix a connected fundamental domain $D$ and consider the set of generators of those $s$ in the fundamental group which map $D$ to one of its neighbours. The Cayley graph you obtain may also be viewed as shrinking $D$ to a point. If you send a potential into the fundamental domain, for each neighbour $E$ Of $D$ there is a certain probability, it comes out at $E$. This results in giving each edge in the Cayley graph a weight. Now the Cayley graph is regular, so one might be able to compute the radius.

Comment: The spectral radius for $K_4-e$ is $\sqrt{1+2\sqrt 7}$ which is the largest zero of $x^4-2x^2-27$. I did it by finding the generating function for closed walks in the cover and it was pretty messy so I'm hoping there is a more systematic way.

Comment: For $K_5-e$ it is the largest zero of the irreducible polynomial $x^{14}-20x^{12}+122x^{10}-152x^8-1295x^6+4540x^4-5948x^2-2000$.  It's not going to get better for larger sizes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the complete graph minus an edge $K_n-e$, the spectral radius is the largest zero of
\begin{align*}&x^{14}+(30-10 n) x^{12}+(2 n^{3}+21 n^{2}-202 n +357) x^{10}\\
&+(-10 n^{4}+26 n^{3}+456 n^{2}-2288 n +2888) x^{8} \\
&+(n^{6}-4 n^{5}+76 n^{4}-1520 n^{3}+9320 n^{2}-23056 n +20360) x^{6}\\
&+(-4 n^{7}+48 n^{6}-272 n^{5}+2184 n^{4}-16472 n^{3}+66016 n^{2}-126496 n +93120) x^{4}\\
& +(4 n^{8}-80 n^{7}+720 n^{6}-4432 n^{5}+22800 n^{4}-91712 n^{3}+242704 n^{2}-358944 n +222672) x^{2}\\
& -16 (n -4)^{3} (n^{2}-6 n +10)^{3}.
\end{align*}
Values for $n=4,5,6,7,8$: 2.50828679, 3.26287647, 3.85572357, 4.36125025, 4.80992000. Experimentally, it is very close to $2\sqrt{n-2}$.

I confess to not tying up every last bit of the proof, but at least the method is valid. Label $K_n-e$ as $0,1,\ldots,n-1$ where $\{0,1\}$ is the missing edge.
Apply the labelling to the cover.

For a vertex $v_i$ labelled $i$ in the cover, and neighbour $v_j$ labelled $j$, let $w_{ij}=w_{ij}(x)$ be the ordinary generating function for closed walks that start at $v_i$, step to $v_j$, then do anything they like except that they only return to $v_i$ in the last step. Because $K_n-e$ is so symmetrical, there are only 3 values for this generating function, represented by $w_{02},w_{20},w_{23}$. Also let $w_0$ be the ogf for all closed walks starting at $v_0$. We can write relations between them:
$$ w_{02} = \frac{x^2}{1-w_{20}-(n-3)w_{23}},\quad
   w_{20} = \frac{x^2}{1-(n-3)w_{02}},  $$
$$  w_{23} = \frac{x^2}{1-2w_{20}-(n-4)w_{23}}
\quad   w_0 = \frac{1}{1-(n-2)w_{02}}. $$
These equations can be solved for $w_0$, though I didn't find any way to write the solution in a pretty form.
It satisfies a quartic polynomial with coefficients that are polynomial in $n,x$.

The final step is to identify the smallest singularity (which is on the real line since all the coefficients are non-negative). The reciprocal of that is the spectral radius.

ADDED Nov 19, 2023:

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2311.07675.pdf) that just appeared on the arXiv is very much related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

An algorithm to compute the spectral radius of the universal cover of a given finite graph is proposed in the paper below. It does not look very practical though.

- Nagnibeda, Tatiana. "Random walks, spectral radii, and Ramanujan
  graphs." Random walks and geometry (2004): 487-500.